# Own document variables with and without arguments

Tags: macros, conditionals, optional-arguments

I use the following to introduce new document variables to my document. They should behave like `\author` or `\title`. So when they're used without parameter, they should print the corresponding variable. If they're called with parameter, they should set the corresponding variable to this value.

```
\newcommand*{\tutor}[1]{\gdef\@tutor{#1}}
```

Works ok, but I have to use

```
\tutor{new defined name}
```

to define the value and

```
\@tutor
```

to get the name printed instead of just using

```
\tutor
```

What's the simplest way to introduce `\tutor` as desired?

Comment: This is not how `\title` and `\author` work. You never use them without the brackets. Commands like `\maketitle` use `\makeatletter\@title\makeatother` etc. internally.

Comment: To push this point home, there is an error in your question. The passage "when they're used without parameter, they should print the corresponding variable" is incorrect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This usage is very uncommon with LaTeX (it's not the way `\author` etc. works), but it is possible to make the macro look ahead with `\@ifnextchar` to see if the next character is a brace (which needs to be written as `\bgroup` because you need a matching pair of braces in the macro).

```
\newcommand*\tutor{%
   \@ifnextchar\bgroup
      {\gdef\@tutor}%
      {\@tutor}%
}
```

This will expand to `\gdef\@tutor` if there is an argument (which will then be taken by it) or to `\@tutor` if not.

---

There is also the `xparse` package which allows to define macros with optional brace arguments and a way to test if the argument was there or not. See the package manual for the details. For this case it is IMHO a little overkill.

---

You could also define `\tutor` in the form you have in your post and redefine it at the begin of the document to be equal to `\@tutor`.

```
\newcommand*{\tutor}[1]{\gdef\@tutor{#1}}
% or
% \newcommand*{\tutor}{\gdef\@tutor}

\AtBeginDocument{\let\tutor\@tutor}
```

Then you can use `\tutor{<argument>}` only in the preamble and `\tutor` only in the document body.

---

Macros with an `@` in the name need to be wrapped in `\makeatletter` ... `\makeatother`, except in package or class files, which do this automatically.

Answer (score 3):

With `xparse`:

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\makeatletter

\def\@tutor{\ClassError{myclass}{Undefined \string\tutor}
  {You need to say \string\tutor{<NAME>} before using \protect\tutor by itself}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\tutor}{g}{\IfNoValueTF{#1}{\@tutor}{\gdef\@tutor{#1}}}

\makeatother
```

I've also added an error message in case `\tutor` is used by itself before having defined its value (such definitions are used in class files, usually).

However, the usual strategy is to avoid having the user print explicitly the tutor's name; so only `\tutor{<NAME>}` should be at the user level and the class can use `\@tutor` to print the title page.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\tutor}[1]{\newcommand{\@tutor}{#1}}
\makeatother
```

and then use it like this

```
\makeatletter\@tutor\makeatother
```

Which is not what you want. However, if you will be using the content a lot, then it is perhaps more usual to encapsulate the above in a `newcommand`

```
\makeatletter\newcommand{\thetutor}[0]{\@tutor}\makeatother
```

You can now use the content of `\@tutor` with `\thetutor`.

In short, it's simpler to just make two commands with a predictable difference between the names (in this case `the`).